# CentOS Multilib problem with libgcc

Tags: centos, node.js, hhvm

My friend's computer running CentOS 5.6, trying to install `hhvm`, but it got an error:

```
$ yum install hhvm
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora.dionipe.web.id
 * rpmforge: mirror.smartmedia.net.id
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package hhvm.x86_64 0:3.2.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glog = 0.3.2 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tbb >= 4 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: oniguruma >= 5.9 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached >= 1.0.9 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libevent >= 1.4.14 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gcc >= 4.6.0 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: curl >= 7.29.0 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost >= 1.54.0 for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: unixODBC for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ocaml for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.19)(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.5)(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdwarf for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ImageMagick for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtbb.so.2()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libonig.so.2()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.11()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjemalloc.so.1()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libglog.so.0()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdwarf.so.0()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_system.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_regex.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.1()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.1()(64bit) for package: hhvm-3.2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ImageMagick.x86_64 0:6.8.6.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfftw3.so.3()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package ImageMagick-libs.x86_64 0:6.8.6.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libImath.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmThread.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmImf.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIex.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libHalf.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: boost-wave = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-timer = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-test = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-signals = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-serialization = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-random = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-python = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-math = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-log = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-locale = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-iostreams = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-graph = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-date-time = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-context = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-chrono = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: boost-atomic = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-filesystem.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-regex.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-system.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-thread.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-46.el6 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-4.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl = 7.29.0-4.el6 for package: curl-7.29.0-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.4 for package: libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-16.el6 for package: gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp = 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc >= 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.2()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
---> Package glog.x86_64 0:0.3.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libunwind.so.8()(64bit) for package: glog-0.3.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package jemalloc.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libc-client.x86_64 0:2007e-11.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdwarf.x86_64 0:20140413-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:1.4.13-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:1.4.14b-2.hphp.el6 will be an update
---> Package libmemcached.x86_64 0:1.0.16-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.4.7-16.el6 for package: libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package ocaml.x86_64 0:3.12.1-12.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rpm-build >= 4.8.0 for package: ocaml-3.12.1-12.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/ocamlrun for package: ocaml-3.12.1-12.el6.x86_64
---> Package oniguruma.x86_64 0:5.9.1-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package tbb.x86_64 0:4.0-7.20120408.el6 will be installed
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-14.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package OpenEXR-libs.x86_64 0:1.6.1-8.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-atomic.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-chrono.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-context.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-date-time.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-graph.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-iostreams.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-locale.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-log.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-math.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-python.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-random.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-serialization.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-signals.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-test.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-timer.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-wave.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package fftw.x86_64 0:3.2.1-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package ilmbase.x86_64 0:1.0.1-6.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-46.el6 will be updated
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-4.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:0.8.3-0.3.svn855.el6 will be installed
---> Package librsvg2.x86_64 0:2.26.0-14.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgsf >= 1.6.0 for package: librsvg2-2.26.0-14.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgsf-1.so.114()(64bit) for package: librsvg2-2.26.0-14.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcroco-0.6.so.3()(64bit) for package: librsvg2-2.26.0-14.el6.x86_64
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be updated
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el6 will be an update
---> Package libunwind.x86_64 0:1.1-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package ocaml-runtime.x86_64 0:3.12.1-12.el6 will be installed
---> Package rpm-build.x86_64 0:4.8.0-55.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rpm = 4.8.0-55.el6 for package: rpm-build-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/gdb-add-index for package: rpm-build-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdb.x86_64 0:7.2-90.el6 will be installed
---> Package libcroco.x86_64 0:0.6.2-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package libgsf.x86_64 0:1.14.15-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: GConf2 for package: libgsf-1.14.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: GConf2 for package: libgsf-1.14.15-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package rpm.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: rpm = 4.8.0-47.el6 for package: rpm-python-4.8.0-47.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: rpm = 4.8.0-47.el6 for package: rpm-libs-4.8.0-47.el6.x86_64
---> Package rpm.x86_64 0:4.8.0-55.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GConf2.x86_64 0:2.28.0-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sgml-common for package: GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: dbus for package: GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libORBit-2.so.0()(64bit) for package: GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6 will be updated
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.8.0-55.el6 will be an update
---> Package rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6 will be updated
---> Package rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.8.0-55.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ORBit2.x86_64 0:2.14.17-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libIDL-2.so.0()(64bit) for package: ORBit2-2.14.17-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package dbus.x86_64 1:1.2.24-8.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package polkit.x86_64 0:0.96-11.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ConsoleKit for package: polkit-0.96-11.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libeggdbus-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: polkit-0.96-11.el6.x86_64
---> Package sgml-common.noarch 0:0.6.3-33.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ConsoleKit.x86_64 0:0.4.1-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libck-connector.so.0()(64bit) for package: ConsoleKit-0.4.1-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package eggdbus.x86_64 0:0.6-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libIDL.x86_64 0:0.8.13-2.1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ConsoleKit-libs.x86_64 0:0.4.1-6.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++ which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++ of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libstdc++.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++ installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++ installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 != libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.i686
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 != libgcc-4.4.7-16.el6.i686
Error: Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-devel-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 != libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-16.el6.i686
```

when I tried to update all simultaneously also got similar error:

```
$ yum update libgcc.x86_64 libgcc.i686 libstdc++.x86_64 libstdc++.i686 libstdc++-devel.x86_64 libstdc++-devel.i686 gcc.x86_64 libtool.x86_64
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora.dionipe.web.id
 * rpmforge: mirror.smartmedia.net.id
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-16.el6 for package: gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp = 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.2-8.el6 for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.2()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
---> Package libgcc.i686 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgcc.i686 0:4.4.7-17.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.4.7-17.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstdc++-devel.i686 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++-devel.i686 0:4.4.7-17.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be updated
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:0.8.3-0.3.svn855.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++-devel which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++-devel of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libstdc++-devel.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++-devel installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++-devel installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-devel-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 != libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-17.el6.i686
Error: Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.4.7-17.el6.i686 != libstdc++-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.i686 != libgcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
```

I guess that the `gcc` is the one block it:

```
yum remove gcc
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.4 for package: libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-16.el6 for package: gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-16.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: gcc-c++ for package: node-gyp-0.10.6-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: gcc-c++ for package: node-gyp-0.10.6-2.el6.noarch
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be erased
--> Running transaction check
---> Package node-gyp.noarch 0:0.10.6-2.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: npm(node-gyp) >= 0.10.6 for package: npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: npm(node-gyp) < 0.11 for package: npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package npm.noarch 0:1.3.6-5.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                             Arch                                                              Version                                                                      Repository                                                        Size
===========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 gcc                                                                 x86_64                                                            4.4.7-16.el6                                                                 @base                                                             19 M
Removing for dependencies:
 gcc-c++                                                             x86_64                                                            4.4.7-16.el6                                                                 @base                                                             11 M
 libtool                                                             x86_64                                                            2.2.6-15.5.el6                                                               @base                                                            1.9 M
 node-gyp                                                            noarch                                                            0.10.6-2.el6                                                                 @epel                                                             66 k
 npm                                                                 noarch                                                            1.3.6-5.el6                                                                  @epel                                                            995 k

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Remove        5 Package(s)

Installed size: 32 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

My friend doesn't want to remove the nodejs, because it still being used.

Is there any solution how to install `hhvm` without removing installed `nodejs`.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  This appears to be a CentOS6 system, not CentOS 5.6.  You appear to have versions of gcc (and related packages) installed that are newer than what are in the CentOS6 repos.  Also, you have the 'rpmforge' repo, which [isn't recommended anymore](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

Once you've disabled rpmforge, try running `yum downgrade gcc`.  You should have something like version 4.4.7-17.el6.